# detach function from on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here's my code:

```
$(function()
{
//code for ajax with autocomplete

$('#autocomplete').on('change', function () {
}).change();

$('#autocomplete').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
// Event code    
}

});
```

So what I basically want to do is to give the name of a "generic", for a lack of a better word, function so that I can call the "Event code" in other places too.

So the line of code should look something like:

```
$('#autocomplete').on('autocompleteselect', genericFunction (e, ui) {
```

The problem is, however, that if you do that, there's an error saying that it can't find symbol "e", and if you remove "e", it can't find "ui".

I need those parameters though, so I can't just take them out.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare a function like this:

```
function eventHandler(e,ui){
    //code here
}
```

and then:

```
$('#autocomplete').on('autocompleteselect', eventHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what I did, but didn't get it working, so starting doing a lot of funny things with the code. There must have been some syntax error somewhere else.